# how to turn off or prevent php glob from escaping back slashes?

Tags: php, json, escaping, glob

with this php code:

```
<? header('Content-type: application/json'); ?>
<?
 $files = glob("sources/".$_GET['dir'].'/img/*');
  echo json_encode($files);
?>
```

I'm getting:

```
 ["sources\/nine\/img\/0010.jpg","sources\/nine\/img\/0011.jpg"]
```

But i want:

```
 ["sources/nine/img/0010.jpg","sources/nine/img/0011.jpg"]
```

Comment: I guess that you don't need escape `/`, I'm wrong? Try to don't escape it.

Comment: hmm... maybe it's fine.  When i load the json from the client, i don't see the escapes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this is not `glob()`, this is `json_encode()`'s doing and it's perfectly okay: It's escaping slashes as suggested by the JSON standard. See this [php.net bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49366&edit=1) for further discussion.

Comment: you are correct, it was just the display that was throwing me off.  The strings themselves did not contain slashes when evaluated on the client side of things.